# Obtener el valor del ultimo dato ingresado e ingresarlo a otro campo en php

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy trabajando un formulario y tengo un problema, quiero pasar el ultimo dato de un campo hacia otro registro en php con mysql.

Esta es mi tabla creada en mysql:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que busco es que la columna KmMant quede así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estuve intentando utilizando el siguiente código pero no obtengo la solución que busco, necesito ayuda por favor.

```html
<?php
$placa=$_POST['placa'];
$recaudacion=$_POST['recaudacion'];
$km=$_POST['km'];
$response=mysql_query("SELECT Km FROM registro ORDER BY  idregistro desc LIMIT 1");
$c=0;
if($response){
 
 while($row = mysql_fetch_row($response)) {
  $codigo=$row['KmMant'];
  $c++;
}
 
}
 
$conexion=mysql_connect("localhost","root","")or die("No se ha podido conectar a la Base de Datos");
mysql_select_db("proyectoprueba", $conexion);
 
mysql_query("INSERT INTO registro VALUES('','$placa',now(),now(),'$recaudacion','$c','$km')");
 
mysql_close($conexion);
echo "Se ha guardado correctamente";
 
?>
```

Comment: Verbalizando el caso: ¿lo que quieres es que tome el valor de la columna `Km` en la última fila para agregarlo en la columna `KmMant` de la nueva fila? Para resolver esto es importante que digas si la columna `idregistro` es autoincremental o no.

Comment: Exacto, eso es lo que busco, si es autoincremental.

Answer (score 0):

Veo que tienes varios registros con la misma placa y la placa seguramente va a variar.

Entonces

Primero tenemos el formulario

```
<form method="POST">
    <div>
        <label>Placa</label>
        <input type="text" name="placa">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Importe</label>
        <input type="text" name="recaudacion">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Km</label>
        <input type="text" name="km">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="">
</form>
```

Luego, veo que usas mysql_connect la cual es una funcion "deprecated" y ya no funciona más en PHP 7 por lo que hay que cambiarlo por mysqli o PDO, en este caso lo hice con mysqli, si no te sirve, de todos modos solo hay que hacer lo mismo con mysql connect.

```
//conectamos a la DB, host, user, pass, dbname
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "placas");

/* verificamos la conexión */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Falló la conexión failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

//hago una pequeña validación para no mandar datos vaciós
if (!empty($_POST['placa']) && !empty($_POST['recaudacion']) && !empty($_POST['km'])) {
    //recogemos los datos por POST
    $placa = $_POST['placa'];
    $recaudacion = $_POST['recaudacion'];
    $km = $_POST['km'];

    //creamos la query
    $query = "SELECT Km FROM registro WHERE Placa = $placa ORDER BY idregistro desc LIMIT 1";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);//ejecutamos

    if ($result) {
        if ($result->num_rows !== 0) {
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);//guardamos el resultado con la funcion assoc
            $kmMant = $row['Km'];//guardamos el dato de km

            $query = "INSERT INTO registro VALUES('', '$placa', now(), now(), '$recaudacion', '$kmMant','$km')";//guardamos los valores del nuevo registro en una query
            $result = $mysqli->query($query);//ejecutamos

            echo "Se ha guardado correctamente";//listo
        } else {
            //si no existe la placa se puede crear
            $query = "INSERT INTO registro VALUES('', '$placa', now(), now(), '$recaudacion', 0,'$km')";//guardamos los valores del nuevo registro en una query
            $result = $mysqli->query($query);//ejecutamos

            echo 'Los datos de la placa no existen se ha creado un nuevo registro';
        }
    }
} else{
    echo "Hay campos vacío";
}
```

El resultado termina así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Espero que te sea de ayuda. Saludos.

Comment: El tema de la placa sale igual, ya que yo mismo ingresé manualmente la misma, intenté aplicar la solución obviando el primer else pero no me funciona, a pesar de que estoy ingresando datos en el formulario me reporta que hay campos vacíos y no me registra nada en la BD